# spawn new instance of msysgit in the same working directory

Tags: windows, git, multiple-instances, msysgit

I am trying to spawn a new instance of msysgit - the git bash shell for windows. I've noticed that the following command is executed when you start from the Start menu:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Therefore I've tried the following commands:

```
start /D /c/Program\ Files/Git/bin sh.exe --login -i
```

and

```
start /D "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" sh.exe --login -i
```

Both don't seem to work.

I want the same feature as that of typing in `start` in a windows classic command prompt. (It opens up a new command prompt window at the same working directory).

Answer (score 0):

This works: `start sh --login -i`